# How do I add my MongoDB shell's download directory to my $PATH variable?

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm just starting to learn how to use Mongodb and I am really not sure how to do this step in the installation process of installing mongo shell.

The official step says to 'Add <your mongo shell's download directory>/bin to your $PATH variable'.

Comment: Hello. In which operating system did you install?

Comment: http://sysadmindata.com/set-mongodb-path-windows/

Comment: I am using MacOS. Im also using the new M1 chip with macOS Big Sur